# FCM unsubscribe specific token From Topic

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm facing now issue that , I have FCM topic and this topic has many subscriber I want the admin removes user from topic not this user unsubscribe by him self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use firebase-admin. You just need to get the users' FCM tokens into an array then  pass in the array of user tokens you would like to

```
// These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
var registrationTokens = [
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1',
  // ...
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n'
];

// Unsubscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens from
// the topic.
admin.messaging().unsubscribeFromTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
  .then(function(response) {
    // See the MessagingTopicManagementResponse reference documentation
    // for the contents of response.
    console.log('Successfully unsubscribed from topic:', response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error unsubscribing from topic:', error);
  });
```

where the registrationTokens are the user tokens and topic is just String of the topic you would want to unscribe the user from.

check out [firebase documentation below on the topi](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_and_unsubscribe_using_the)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the (registration/instance ID) tokens of that user, you can [use the Admin SDK to unsubscribe them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics#subscribe-and-unsubscribe-using-instance-id-apis). Note that using the Admin SDK must happen in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

The API to unsubscribe tokens from topics is available in the Admin SDKs for [Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#unsubscribe-from-topic), [Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging.html#unsubscribeFromTopic(java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%20java.lang.String)), [Python](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.messaging#unsubscribe_from_topic), [Go](https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/messaging#Client), and [.NET](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet/class/firebase-admin/messaging/firebase-messaging#unsubscribefromtopicasync).